# Navigation Motion to Skip Comments

Tags: vim

To edit configuration files, I'm using Vim. In order to move the cursor upwards or downwards to other configuration entries, I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, respectively. Large blocks of commented lines with few configuration lines messes it all up, and I often oversee non-commented lines.

Is there a a kind of motion to move the cursor down to the next non-commented line without using hard to type regular expressions?

Comment: There's this plugin for programming languages: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4581

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regexp just once (something like `/^[^#]`, i.e. find a line which starts with other than `#` character) and then search for next occurence with simple `n` command.

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question:

> Is there a a kind of motion to move the cursor down to the next non-commented line without using hard to type regular expressions?

No there isn't any direct way to do this beyond using a regular expression such as  `:/^[^#]`. There are other plugins to Vim which you can use such as [vim-identifier-movement](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4581), which allow you to move the cursor in other ways but they do not give you the ability to skip over comments directly.

*excerpt*

> #### description
>
> vim plugin, one way to improve move using "w W b B", 
>   smartly move between language identifier, skip language
>   keywords,comment,strings
>
> default key mapping:  `<C-n>` next language identifier `<C-p>` previous
>   language identifier
>
> current support language:  c, c++, vim, python